# How to Curve_fit audio wav

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize

for my internship project, I have to perform an audio analysis. But I have an error of have I do not see the solution. Once after converting the .wav audio to audio spectrum I would like to simplify to clearly see the peaks. So I imagine that it is necessary to make a curve of tendency but my curve_fit does not work.

thank you for your concern.

```
from scipy import fftpack
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

AudioName = "Bulletin1.wav"
fs, Audiodata = wavfile.read(AudioName)

fourier = fftpack.fft(Audiodata)
power = np.abs(fourier)
freq = fftpack.fftfreq(Audiodata.size)
freq = np.abs(freq)
fourier = np.abs(fourier)
fourier[power<1200000] = 0

p = curve_fit(fourier,freq,power)

plt.plot(freq,fourier)
```

error:
TypeError: array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]) is not a callable object

Comment: In https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html you have to pass a callable as 1st argument (i.e. a function), you're passing an array. PS: why don't you perform a periodogram? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html?highlight=periodogram#scipy.signal.periodogram

Comment: Thank you. I will try to solve this problem with the function (for knowledge), but if it is more interesting with a periodogram then I will favor this method.